# Regex for redirecting old versions of web app to latest in IIS 7

Tags: regex, iis-7, url-rewriting

I recently discovered IIS7+ URL rewriter and am trying to use it to redirect requests using pattern match.

I would like to redirect all requests for old version(s)' paths to the latest release path. The version is appended to the website path and incremented with each release like this:

```
Website1RC1 --> Website2 --> ... to Website22RC15
```

Where each part in the path above:

```
Website = Fixed
1-100 = Always there
RC = Optional
1-100 = Optional
```

Having the latest version known and knowing that the versions are incremental, is there a way to have a single regular expression which will match all old versions? What I would want to avoid offcourse is the expression mactching the latest version otherwise it will end up in a infinite redirects.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of to do something like this is with the grouping mechanism, where you explicitly match the latest with a literal match and match the others with a general expression. Then you check the contexts of the general match, as in the following, demonstrated [here](http://rubular.com/r/Ug4q4LNYkq):

`^(?:(Website22RC15)|(Website1?\d{1,2}(?:RC)?1?\d{1,2}))$`

I thought there might be a way with the negative "look ahead" and "look behind" capability, but that seems to only work in conjunction with matching a different string before or after what you're interested in.

BTW, note that if the RC is present, there is generally no way to distinguish between the two integers.